# Suppose $f$ is not decreasing. Furthermore, suppose $\int_{0}^{1}f(x) = 0$, then $f(x) = 0$ on $[0,1]$

Tags: calculus

I am stuck on a proof for my class.

**Question**
Suppose $f$ is not decreasing. Furthermore, suppose $$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx =0.$$ Then $f(x) = 0 $ on $[0, 1]$.

**My Reasoning**

True. The only the intergral evaluates to $0$ is if $f(x) = 0$.

Someone told me that my answer is not correct. But why?

Comment: $f(x)=x-\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: see Baby Rudin exercise 6.2 https://minds.wisconsin.edu/handle/1793/67009 this is the answers

Comment: @pie This is a completely different problem.

Comment: @Mark my mistake!! sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple counterexample here:
$$\int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx = (F(x)+C) \rvert_{0}^{1} = F(1)-F(0) = 0$$
which is also
$$ F(1) = F(0) $$
let F(x) to be, let's say
$$F(x) = c*x*(x-1) = c * (x^2 - x)$$ where c could be arbitrary const number
thus
$$f(x) = 2cx-c = c(2x-1)$$
is not gonna be always 0 on [0, 1]
so the statement would be false